# document.getElementsById is not a function at window.onload

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Help me please?

document.getElementsById is not a function
    at window.onload

```
window.onload = function () {
    temp = document.getElementsById("temperature");
    loc = document.getElementsById("location");
    icon = document.getElementsById("icon");
    humidity = document.getElementsById("humidity");
    wind = document.getElementsById("wind");
    direction = document.getElementsById("direction");

}
```

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future. There is no `getElementsById` (note the plural) function in the DOM. There is a `getElementById` (singular), because `id`s **must** be unique in the document, so it makes no sense to have the plural form.

Comment: There is no `getElementsById` so that seems right

Comment: getElementsById doesn't exist, "getElementById" Yes.

Comment: Side note: Unless you have declarations you haven't shown, that code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables. :-)

Answer (score -1):

The native function you're looking for is called `document.getElementById`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Getting multiple elements by a single ID wouldn't make sense since an ID should be unique within a DOM tree.

Comment: Look at your console @DrRick. Any more errors. Maybe you should add html and code to your question.